# vim get error properly formatted in quickfix

Tags: quickfix, error, errorformat

Please find my minimal vimrc (whatever I use for Latex compilation)

```
"General "{{{
set nocompatible                     "  because vim is not vi
"set autowrite                       "  write on shell commands
"set autoread                        "  read on change outside vim
set spell spl=en_us                  "  Set Spell
set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
set tags=tags;/
syntax enable
" let mapleader=","
"}}}
set encoding=utf8
""}}}

" VimPlug {{{
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'dense-analysis/ale'
Plug 'vim-latex/vim-latex'                      , {'for': 'tex'}                      "
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim'                      , {'branch':'release'}
Plug 'skywind3000/asyncrun.vim'
call plug#end()
filetype plugin indent on
"}}}

"LaTeX {{{2
augroup FT_LaTex
  autocmd BufReadPost *.tex setlocal filetype=tex
  au FileType tex let b:ale_linters =  ['texlab']
  au filetype tex let b:ale_fixers = ['latexindent', 'remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace']  
  let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
  let g:Tex_CustomTemplateDirectory='/home/rudra/Templates/Latex'
  " let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'
  " let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'evince_dbus.py'
  " let g:Tex_Debug = 1
  " let g:Tex_DebugLog = '/tmp/vim-latex-suite.log'
  let g:Tex_FoldedMisc = 'preamble,<<<'
  au FileType tex inoremap "" ``"<++><esc>4hi
  au FileType bib inoremap "" ""<++><esc>4hi
  au FileType tex inoremap <<< %<<<
  au VimLeavePre  *.tex  exe "! latexmk -c"
  au filetype tex syntax region texZone start='\\begin{minted}' end='\\end{minted}'
augroup END
"}}}2

" LANGUAGE SERVER {{{
if match (&runtimepath, "coc.nvim") !=-1 
  let g:coc_start_at_startup = 0
  augroup coc
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * :silent CocStart
  augroup end
  let g:coc_user_config = {
        \   'languageserver': {
        \     'latex': {
        \       'command': '/home/rudra/.local/bin/texlab',
        \       'ignoredRootPaths':['~'],
        \       'filetypes': ['tex', 'bib', 'plaintex', 'context'],
        \     }
        \   }
        \ }
else
  echom ('install coc.nvim')
endif


" ALE {{{
let g:ale_sign_error = 'EE'
let g:ale_sign_warning = 'ww'
let g:ale_set_loclist = 0
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
" let g:ale_fixers = ['remove_trailing_lines', 'trim_whitespace'] 
" }}}


" AsyncRun {{{
" Quick run via <F10>
nnoremap <F10> :call <SID>compile_and_run()<CR><Esc>
inoremap <buffer> <F10> <Esc> :call <SID>compile_and_run()<CR><Esc>
function! s:compile_and_run()
  exec 'w'
  if &filetype == 'tex'
    exec "AsyncRun!  latexmk -pdflua -pvc --synctex=1 -shell-escape  %"
  elseif &filetype == 'sh'
    exec "AsyncRun! time bash %"
  endif
endfunction
let g:asyncrun_open = 15
"}}}
```

And a mwe.tex:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
    Hello World
\end{minipage}
\thisiserror
\small{
    \begin{tabular}[h]{|p{.35\textwidth}|p{.08\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|}\hline
        Hello & World & \makebox[\linewidth][s]{\spaceout{0123456789}} \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

The problem is, when I run from terminal, I get the error very neat and clean as:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \thisiserror
               
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \spaceout 
          {0123456789}
l.13 ...akebox[\linewidth][s]{\spaceout{0123456789}}
                                                   \\\hline
?
```

But if I am compiling inside vim as

```
exec "AsyncRun!  latexmk -pdflua -pvc --synctex=1 -shell-escape  %"
```

in quickfix, I get not so helpful output:

```
mwe.tex|| Undefined control sequence.
mwe.tex|| Emergency stop.
mwe.tex|| ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I add

```
au filetype tex set errorformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

in augroup `FT_Latex`, I am getting complete compilation, and not the error only.

What I can do?

Also, how I can check all the errorformat active in my vim.

The format I am looking for is: line no: Error

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what 'errorformat' does.

It's not "please display errors like so", rather "here's what errors look like, please find them".

More precisely, each line of the output of `makeprg` is matched against each member `errorformat`.

Your example, `%f:%l:%c:%m`, works for an output that looks like:

```
file:3:2:this is an error message
```

As such a line can't be found in your output, no error can be extracted.

`latexmk` seems to be quite difficult to write an errorformat for, so you may want to try another tool for the job.
[vimwiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Compiling_LaTeX_from_Vim) suggests `rubber` whith this errorformat:

```
setlocal errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m,%f:%l-%\\d%\\+:\ %m
```

Some help topics:

- [:h :errorformat](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#errorformats)
- [:h :makeprg](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27)

Answer (score 1):

As Biggybi notes, there may be a misunderstanding as I'm not sure if you want the quickfix window to correctly interpret the output of latexmk or you want it to display the errors in a different way.  If it's the latter, then you'll want to look at [`:h quickfix-window-function`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix-window-function) which enables you to customise this, although note that it is still a single line of text per error.

For latexmk, [I use](https://github.com/andrewlkho/dotfiles/blob/master/tag-vim/local/etc/vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim) the following errorformat which was taken from [a previous commit](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/98327bfe0e599bf580e61cfaa6216c8d4177b23d/compiler/latexmk.vim) of the [vimtex plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex):

```
setlocal makeprg=latexmk\ %:S
" https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/98327bfe0e599bf580e61cfaa6216c8d4177b23d/compiler/latexmk.vim
setlocal errorformat=%-P**%f
setlocal errorformat+=%-P**\"%f\"
setlocal errorformat+=%E!\ LaTeX\ %trror:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%E%f:%l:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%E!\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%Z<argument>\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%Cl.%l\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%+WLaTeX\ Font\ Warning:\ %.%#line\ %l%.%#
setlocal errorformat+=%-CLaTeX\ Font\ Warning:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(Font)%m
setlocal errorformat+=%+WLaTeX\ %.%#Warning:\ %.%#line\ %l%.%#
setlocal errorformat+=%+WLaTeX\ %.%#Warning:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%+WOverfull\ %\\%\\hbox%.%#\ at\ lines\ %l--%*\\d
setlocal errorformat+=%+WUnderfull\ %\\%\\hbox%.%#\ at\ lines\ %l--%*\\d
setlocal errorformat+=%+WPackage\ natbib\ Warning:\ %m\ on\ input\ line\ %l%.
setlocal errorformat+=%+WPackage\ biblatex\ Warning:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(biblatex)%.%#in\ t%.%#
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(biblatex)%.%#Please\ v%.%#
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(biblatex)%.%#LaTeX\ a%.%#
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(biblatex)%m
setlocal errorformat+=%-Z(babel)%.%#input\ line\ %l.
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(babel)%m
setlocal errorformat+=%+WPackage\ hyperref\ Warning:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(hyperref)%.%#on\ input\ line\ %l.
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(hyperref)%m
setlocal errorformat+=%+WPackage\ scrreprt\ Warning:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(scrreprt)%m
setlocal errorformat+=%+WPackage\ fixltx2e\ Warning:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(fixltx2e)%m
setlocal errorformat+=%+WPackage\ titlesec\ Warning:\ %m
setlocal errorformat+=%-C(titlesec)%m
setlocal errorformat+=%-G%.%#
```

And also have the following in my latexmkrc:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S"
```

This means that latexmk errors are interpreted correctly and displayed in the quickfix window, one error per line (which is how the quickfix window is intended to show errors) like so:

[image: quickfix]

I'm afraid I don't use continuous compilation (`-pvc`) so I haven't tested how it would interact with that.